# Address Sanitizer with Ruby Nokogiri module

Tags: ruby, address-sanitizer

I am trying to compile Address Sanitizer in nokogiri Ruby gem.

Compiled libxml2 and libxslt with Address Sanitizer like this:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-fsanitize=address,undefined -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Werror=array-bounds -g" CXXFLAGS="-fsanitize=address,undefined -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Werror=array-bounds -g" LDFLAGS="-fsanitize=address,undefined" CC="clang" CXX="clang++"
```

And installed gem like this:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri --version 1.8.0 -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/home/user/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.3/include/ --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/lib/ --with-cflags=\"-fsanitize=address\" --with-ldflags=\"-fsanitize=address -lasan -lubsan\" --with-xslt-include=/home/user/Downloads/libxslt-1.1.28/ --with-xslt-lib=/usr/local/lib/
```

However when I run sample Ruby script using Nokogiri

script.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'nokogiri'

doc = File.open("sample.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
```

I get this message:

```
 ./script.rb 
==30473==ASan runtime does not come first in initial library list; you should either link runtime to your application or manually preload it with LD_PRELOAD.
```

When I do the preload:

```
 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2 ./script.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so: undefined symbol: __asan_init - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from ./script.rb:2:in `<main>'

    =================================================================
    ==30485==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

    Direct leak of 319176 byte(s) in 4259 object(s) allocated from:
        #0 0x7fce9ea4579a in __interceptor_calloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x9879a)
        #1 0x7fce9e5b4383 in ruby_xcalloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.3.so.2.3+0x85383)

.
.
.
```

Do I have to build Ruby also with Address Sanitizer? Which unfortunately fails ...

```
cd ruby-2.3.0
./configure --disable-shared CFLAGS="-fsanitize=address -ggdb" CXXFLAGS="-fsanitize=address -ggdb"
make
```

Breaks upon compilation, showing Memory Leak :/

How do I correctly enable Address Sanitizer in Ruby, on Ruby Gem?

Thanks,

**Update 1:**

Tried also passing "undefined" as @yugr suggested, but does not help:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri --version 1.8.0 -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/home/user/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.3/include/ --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/lib/ --with-cflags=\"-fsanitize=address,undefined\" --with-ldflags=\"-fsanitize=address,undefined -lasan -lubsan\" --with-xslt-include=/home/user/Downloads/libxslt-1.1.28/
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/home/user/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.3/include/ --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/lib/ --with-cflags="-fsanitize=address,undefined" --with-ldflags="-fsanitize=address,undefined -lasan -lubsan" --with-xslt-include=/home/user/Downloads/libxslt-1.1.28/'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.8.0
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.8.0
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

**Update 2:**

Successfully compiled Ruby, libxml2, libxst and Nokogiri  with ASan, but when I run it I still get:

```
./ruby ../script.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
    7: from ../script.rb:1:in `<main>'
    6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: undefined symbol: __asan_init - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so (LoadError)
```

Comment: Could you try configuring with `LDFLAGS=-fsanitize=adress,undefined`?

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but go the same message in regards to ASan

Comment: Hmmm trying now to compile Ruby with ASAN with disabled LeakSanitizer (export ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0) ... goes further. It didnt compile previously due to leaks errors.

Comment: Compiled the Ruby successfully, but the error with "undefined symbol: __asan_init" still occurs

Comment: I think part of the problem may be that you built part of the code with clang and other with gcc. Asan implementation in both is sadly incompatible.

Comment: Thanks! Ok so I should try to build everything either in gcc or clang. Can you specify which configure flags I should use in gcc and which in clang? In Internet there is so many confusing answers.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately GCC and Clang implementation differ in some details. External interface is the same for both though: add `-fsanitize=address` to `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. And use the same `CC` and `CXX` settings for all projects (`clang`, `gcc` or just leave undefined and it'll select `gcc` automatically).

Comment: OK WORKS :) Compiled everything using GCC with the flags you have suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it to work.

Compiled everything using GCC using these flags:

-fsanitize=address to CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS